# Is DateTimeFormatter Operating System Dependent?

Tags: java, time, formatting, datetimeformatter

The following code:

```java
Locale locale = new java.util.Locale("en", "AU");
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM).withLocale(locale);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-11-19T14:13:12Z");
return fmt.format(zdt);
```

gives me different results depending on operating system:

| OS | Format | Java |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Windows | 19 Nov. 2021, 2:13:12 pm | 1.8.0_312 |
| macOS | 19 Nov 2021, 2:13:12 pm | 1.8.0_312 |
| Linux/Ubuntu | 19/11/2021, 2:13:12 PM | 1.8.0_292 |

is this expected? My unit tests fail in different contexts, and it seems rather unexpected to me

Comment: I fail to see where the test actually uses the created `Locale locale = new java.util.Locale("en", "AU");`. Did you mean to write `...withLocale(locale);` instead of `.withLocale(context.getLocale());`?

Comment: FormatStyle.SHORT also differs : windows & OSX ```19/11/21, 2:13 pm```, ```Linux 19/11/21 2:13 PM```

Comment: oh yes, forgot to simplify that bit, thanks - updated

Comment: All three environments use the same exact JVM?

Comment: great question. 
Mac = Java version: 1.8.0_312, vendor: Temurin in 'en-US' locale. 
Linux =  Java version: 1.8.0_292, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK in 'en' Locale. 
Windows = Java version: 1.8.0_312, vendor: Temurin in 'en-US' locale

Comment: So... Mac and Windows produce the same result and are on the same version from the samve vendor witht the same locale. Linux is not. Could you try setting the locale and bumping the installation to the same version and the same vendor for the linux machine?

Comment: Mac and Windows are not the same result - missing '.' on OSX (or vice versa). I don't control the build pipeline, I'll ask about changing it. But the default locale shouldn't matter?

Comment: Question: how can we (you and us) be sure that the code you've shown is actually representative of what's running? You've already made at least 2 mistakes when transcribing it - once to omit the time portion of the output, and once because you weren't using the Locale instance. How can we be sure that your real tests aren't running something different to what you've shown here? It seems most likely that you're using a different Locale on each machine without realising it.

Comment: @xerx593 The part of your comment in parentheses makes no sense to me. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: assuming/believing that different OS, produce different results (with the same FormatStyle), ... it is still consistent with (FormatStyle) javadoc...when you consider OS not beyond/above/beside locale, but as "specialization of locale" (like in `java.util.Properties`)

Comment: ..where e.g. `my_en_US_MAC.properties` has "higher precedence than & inherits from" `my_en.properties`

Comment: "how can we (you and us) be sure that the code you've shown is actually representative of what's running?" - reasonable question, so I added https://github.com/hapifhir/org.hl7.fhir.core/blob/gg-202111-locale-consistency-test/org.hl7.fhir.r5/src/test/java/org/hl7/fhir/r5/test/NarrativeGeneratorTests.java#L80

Comment: outcomes: 

osx: expected:<19 Nov[.] 2021, 2:13:12 pm> but was:<19 Nov[] 2021, 2:13:12 pm>
linux: expected:<19[ Nov. 2021, 2:13:12 pm]> but was:<19[/11/2021 2:13:12 PM]>
windows: expected:<19 Nov[.] 2021, 2:13:12 pm> but was:<19 Nov[] 2021, 2:13:12 pm>

(my vm is Oracle/Win64, different to the pipeline windows vm). So it's vendor dependent...

Comment: Your code says English Australia. But [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70059067/is-datetimeformatter-operating-system-dependent#comment123845498_70059067) says English United States. Which is it? Did you use various locales? Of course you’ll get different results with different locales. Voting to close as unclear. This [Question is highly suspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70059067/is-datetimeformatter-operating-system-dependent#comment123845597_70059067) at this time, and I think you’ve been wasting the valuable time of several people. The up-votes are undeserved.

Comment: My comment you refer to says what the default locale of the jvm is. And I referred to the actual code directly, and provided the results of running it. I don't believe I'm wasting people's time, and the fact that the code I provided gives different results on different VMs/OSs is not otherwise a known fact so far as I can tell

Comment: And you edited my question to quote jvm version, but in fact all the pipelines (3 jvm versions on 3 OSes) give the same result by version - so I'm not sure whether I should clarify that since I think jvm version is not relevent.

Comment: @GrahameGrieve Thank you. I checked your Azure pipeline and your conclusions seem very strange to me. It seems to be nothing to do with vendor or OS, and everything to do with the specific JDK version. Java 7 used a period after the name of the month, Java 8 used a lowercase AM/PM, and Java 11 uses uppercase. You are comparing everything with the Java 11 string. The JDK updates locale data periodically so it's not surprising.

Comment: I get `19 Nov 2021, 2:13:12 pm` (with no dot) both on Windows (Java 15) and Mac (Java 17).  On Java 1.8.0_271 on Windows I get `19/11/2021 2:13:12 PM`. Combining you observations and mine it seems to be more Java version dependent than OS dependent.

Comment: Sigh. you're right. Version dependent, and I have no excuse for missing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Java 8: no expected dependency on operating system

The Java Runtime engine has had locale data built-in since early versions of Java. From Java 8 data from Unicode Common Locale Data Repository, CLDR, are also included with Java, but default Java’s own data are still preferred.

The result from formatting date and time using your formatter is expected to depend on three or four factors:

1. On locale.
2. On the provider of the locale data. Java can get its locale data from up to four sources: the JRE’s own data, CLDR, an installed service provider (so yourself, so to speak) and the host operating system. Which ones are used and with what priority is controlled by the `java.locale.providers` system property.
3. On the versions of the locale data from the selected providers.
4. In case of the `HOST` locale data provider obviously on the operating system.

In **Java 8** the default is to use the JRE’s own locale data as first priorioty and any configured service provider second. Not the host operating system in any case. So not setting the system property `java.locale.providers` is equivalent to setting it to `JRE,SPI`. Which in turn does not incur any dependency on the operating system.

In **Java 9** the default was changed to be equivalent to `CLDR,COMPAT` where `COMPAT` is the new name for `JRE`. Which in turn still does not incur any dependency on the operating system.

### Why did you observe different results?

Assuming that you are relying on the default locale data providers, JRE and SPI, and that you have not added your own service provider (SPI), your different results must be caused by different versions of Java’s locale data. So apparently they updated the locale data from Java 1.8.0_292 to 1.8.0_312.

The slight difference between Windows and Mac both running 1.8.0_312, the dot after `Nov`, then? While I would have expected them to ship the same version of the locale data with Java installers for different operating systems, the explanation that I can think of is that in this case they may not have.

### More observed results

I did some runs of your code too. The following table includes your observations and mine. In all runs I have set `java.locale.providers` to `JRE,SPI` to get Java 8 behaviour on Java 9 and later too.

| Java | Format | OS | Tester |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.8.0_121 | 19/11/2021, 2:13:12 PM | MacOS | Me |
| 1.8.0_271 | 19/11/2021, 2:13:12 PM | Windows | Me |
| 1.8.0_292 | 19/11/2021, 2:13:12 PM | Ubuntu | You |
| 1.8.0_312 | 19 Nov. 2021, 2:13:12 pm | Windows | You |
| 1.8.0_312 | 19 Nov 2021, 2:13:12 pm | MacOS | You |
| 9.0.4 | 19 Nov 2021, 2:13:12 pm | MacOS | Me |
| 15.0.1 | 19/11/2021 2:13:12 PM | Windows | Me |

The last result is funny, as is your result with the dot.

### Links

- Documentation of [`LocaleServiceProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html)
- [Internationalization Enhancements in JDK 9 — CLDR Locale Data Enabled by Default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/intl/internationalization-enhancements-jdk-9.htm#GUID-9DCDB41C-A989-4220-8140-DBFB844A0FCA)

Comment: Yes, at least mostly version related